# ValueError: operation parameter must be str issue

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I keep getting this error "ValueError: operation parameter must be str". Having looked on here, I still couldn't figure out what was wrong in my code.

```
def returnCard(name, ID, rollingBalance):
    rollingBalance = float(rollingBalance)
    print(rollingBalance)
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = 'update Atm set Balance=? Where=?',(rollingBalance, ID,)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    print("Thank you for using Norther Frock")
    print("Returning card...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Have a nice day")
    entryID()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass sql and parameter separately instead of single argument containing tuples

```
sql = 'update Atm set Balance=? Where=?'
cursor.execute(sql,(rollingBalance, ID))
db.commit()
```

> after Where clause you are missing column name

Comment: , line 117, in returnCard
    cursor.execute(sql,(rollingBalance, ID))
ValueError: operation parameter must be str             I'm still getting that error message when I implement this

Comment: you are trying to update balance where is equal to provided id right??

Comment: I'm trying to update balance with rollingBalance! ID gives the program which users balance it is updating

Comment: It might give you error like > "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error"
cuase you are missing column name after where clause but otherwise it is working good!

Comment: Fixed it, no worries! Have a nice day! Yes, I was missing a column error too btw, so you had the right fix!

Comment: yah! same as mentioned over here. and if answer is useful accept it so other people have same issue get better idea of solution.

Answer (score 0):

`rollingBalance = float(rollingBalance)`
So now, what type would you expect rollingBalance to be? Similar for ID, I would  guess it is not a string either (though I do not know).

Also, if memory serves me right(from PHP, that is), you have to do `WHERE ID=%`, else it will try to interpret the ID as boolean and all accounts will be changed!

Try replacing line 6 with `sql = 'update Atm set Balance=%s Where ID=%s'%(str(rollingBalance),str(ID))`